# what's wrong with .match() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery says:
http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#RegExp

> All RegExp operations should be done
>   using .test() and .exec().
>   "string".match() is no longer used.

Why is .match() not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major benefit of `exec` is that it returns capturing groups. For example:

```
var s = "123456789"
var regex = /.(.)(..)/g;
```

match:

```
s.match(regex);
> [1234, 5678]
```

exec:

```
regex.exec(s);
> [1234, 2, 34]
regex.exec(s);
> [5678, 6, 78]
```

Reviewing the coding standards you've posted; the document contains many seemingly arbitrary guidelines. Obviously, it aims to achieve mostly consistency, so it is possible `exec` is preferred because it has more functionality - it *has* to be used on some occasions, so they might as well use it always.

On a personal note, I don't care much for guidelines without explanations, so it's a good thing you've asked. In many cases it leads to dogmatic or superstition-based programming.

Comment: `"On a personal note, I don't care much for guidelines without explanations"` -- Amen, brother.  +1

Comment: `match()` returns query-groups, the same, when the `/g` option is omitted.  You just can't cycle through the string like `exec()` can.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

### Given:

```
var Str             = 'Here are some words.';
var myRegex         = /(\w+)/ig;
```

.

### With match():

```
var aWordList       = Str.match (myRegex);
var iLen            = aWordList.length;

for (var K=0;  K < iLen;  K++)
{
    console.log ('Word: ', K, ' --> ', aWordList[K]);
}
```

.

### With exec():

```
var aWordList;
var K               = 0;

RegExp.lastindex    = 0;    //-- If this is omitted, nasty side-effects may occur.

while ( (aWordList = myRegex.exec (Str)) != null)
{
    console.log ('Word: ', K++, ' --> ', aWordList[0]);
}
```

.

See how much simpler `exec()` is?
(Me neither.)

Both functions are fully supported according to my chart (except that `match()` results also have the `input` member on IE).

I couldn't find a justification for the decision by the folks at jQuery.

Comment: +1. By the way, that would be easier to read (imo) if the titles weren't in comments, but SO titles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a style thing.

The big difference is that `match` is called like so:

```
string.match(regex)
```

While `test` and `exec` are called like so:

```
regex.exec(string)
```